# One more "Mutated while being enumerated" issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, fast-enumeration

I faced "`Collection <_NSFaultingMutableSet: 0x7fac9c011190> was mutated while being enumerated`" issue.

I know what it means, I found it on SO. I spotted the line which causes this exception. But I still can't get what exactly I'm mutating here. Could you please help me figure that out?

```
- (void)addEntitiesObject:(Entity *)value {
    for (Group* group in value.groups) {
        Group* groupToAddObjectTo = nil;
        for (Group* tabGroup in self.tab.groups) {
            if (group.title == tabGroup.title) {
                groupToAddObjectTo = tabGroup;
            }
        }
        if (!groupToAddObjectTo)
            groupToAddObjectTo = [self.fetchController createGroup];

        groupToAddObjectTo.title = group.title;
        [groupToAddObjectTo addEntitiesObject:value]; //THIS LINE IS A TROUBLE
        [self.tab addGroupsObject:groupToAddObjectTo];
    }
}
```

The method `addEntitiesObject` that causes a problem is generated by XCode with "`Create NSManagedObject subclass...`". I never define it.

Method "createGroup" only inserts new Group in CoreData with

```
    Group* group = (Group*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

and returns the group.

So my point is that I'm not using `groupToAddObjectTo` while it is in the loop where it is assigned to an element of `NSSet`, so what's the problem here?

Comment: where is 'addEntitiesObject' defined and does it modify value or value.groups? since you are iterating over value.groups, that would be a problem.

Comment: @RobP I'm not defining it. It's declared by XCode in Groups class. I never define it, as it might be defined by CoreData. So I have no idea what it really does under the hood.

Comment: Do you have an inverse relationship from the group back to the `value.groups`? If so, this will cause your problem because when you add value to the group, value.groups will be mutated

Comment: @Paulw11 self.tab.groups is NSSet, self.tab is NSManagedObject. And yes, it does have a inverse relationship. Let me check, whether it works, if I remove inverse relationships.

Comment: @Paulw11 The crash has gone. So you were right, that was the issue. Could you please make it an answer, so I could accept it. I think others will benefit from it too. Thank you very much, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an inverse relationship from groups back to the `value` entity, then adding the entity to a group will modify the `value.groups` property - which will cause your error as your outer loop is enumerating `value.groups`.

Either remove the inverse relationship, or if you need to keep it, copy the `value.groups` property and enumerate the copy.

Comment: Can you please explain it more or can you please show a simple example?

Comment: Which part needs more explanation?  If you mutate a collection while you are iterating it, you get an exception.  In the question, the code is adding a new `Group` entity in some cases.  It then sets a relationship from that group to the `value` entity.  Since there is an inverse relationship, Core Data updates the `value` entity's `groups` set to refer to the new `Group` - This is the set that is being enumerated by the outer `for` loop, so an exception is thrown